# Create a (hard coded) matrix within VBA as array

Tags: arrays, vba, matrix

In VBA we can use Array() to create a vector (1D array),
eg. `Vector = Array(1,2,3)`

How can we create a 2x3 matrix? How would it be 3x2? 
eg. `Matrix = Array(1,2,3;4,6,7)`

Thanks

**Attempt**

Method one below is a solution albeit cumbersome. Is there something nimble/larger arrays?

```
Option Explicit 1

Private Sub MatrixDemo()
  Dim arr(2,3) as Variant   ' Which has 2 rows and 3 columns       
  arr(1,1) = 1          
  arr(1,2) = 2          
  arr(1,3) = 3                      
  arr(2,1) = 4           
  arr(2,2) = 5             
  arr(2,3) = 6           
End Sub
```

Method 2 is more nimble but i have to set the commas to define the dimension. Can we run this on the fly?

```
Dim matrix = New Integer(2, 3) {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {6, 7}}
```

Comment: for populating a 2D-Array you will need a loop

Comment: the loop only works if there is a calculation whereby the contents is a fn of (i,j) location ??

Comment: I would suggest the following documentation from Microsoft Developper Network [Declaring Arrayss in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x397t1yt(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This function will return the matrix you want.

Just pass it the rows and columns you need `Create_Matrix(3, 2)` and it will retrun an array with incremented values.

```
Function Create_Matrix(x As Long, y As Long) As Variant

    Dim Arr() As Variant ' Matrix array
    Dim i As Long ' rows
    Dim j As Long ' columns
    Dim k As Long ' increment counter


    ReDim Arr(1 To y, 1 To x)

    For i = 1 To y

        For j = 1 To x

            k = k + 1

            Arr(i, j) = k

        Next j ' next column


    Next i ' next row


    Create_Matrix = Arr

End Function
```

Your array should be first declared `Variant`

Comment: This creates a matrix of consecutive numbers. What about transforming a vector, given matrix dimensions, into a matrix?